# Working with Notification Intent in an Android app (with PhoneGap)

Tags: cordova, android-intent, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I'm working on implementing push notifications into my android application. I have the notifications working and displaying in the status bar, which is good. However, because i am using Phonegap, my application understandably "exists" at least in terms of user experience in the various html and js files in my www folder.

Currently, my approach to handling the action of a notification click from the notification drawer is to get the payload from the GCM server (in my Receiver class), check the text of the message, and then depending on what it says, add a url that points toward a specific file to the Bundle payload, finally passing this in the intent to the main activity.

Once I click one of these notifications and i am directed to a page (using super.Url(some_file_location) immediately following the line super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); ). The problem is that my app's savedInstanceState seems to be forgotten or unreachable after this is carried out, and thus, if I re-open the application i am automatically redirected to the login page (which I have as an alternative if the intent.getExtras() bundle == null). If instead I never send the app a push notification, it seems the application remembers its last state when I access it again.

Unfortunately, I cannot provide any code. However, if anyone can explain conceptually how a notification intent tends to behave, or simply offer some good coding practices for working with the savedInstanceState, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: First, you'll want to save the logged in user in `SharedPreferences` as when in the background, at any time, _Android may stop your app to obtain more memory for other applications_; when this happens, `savedInstanceState` will no longer be available.  Also, _Cordova (PhoneGap) is weird in how it exits/pauses the application_, at least in 3.4.x; review the behavior of how the `keepRunning` preference (set in config.xml) is handled in `CordovaActivity`, and you'll see what I'm talking about.  No matter how the application is launched from your notification, `getIntent()` should be consistent.

Comment: @myninjaname Thank you for the response, I didn't realize that savedInstanceState could be made unavailable. I think I may have worded my question slightly incorrectly. When the application begins, my Login page is loaded because savedInstanceState == null. Thus, it seems that after I am taken to the application via a Notification, the savedInstanceState once again becomes null. Is there any way to "reset" it before the Intent is carried out? Hope that makes sense. Thanks again

Comment: Rather than saving the login state in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`, save the login state immediately once its created using `getSharedPreferences("<my_app_key>", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()[.putString(..)].commit()`.